# Cannot run Xuggler on linux

Tags: java, xuggle

I have a problem running Xuggler on linux:

```
08:43:05.550 [main] WARN  com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary - Failure: library load of library: xuggle; url: /tmp/xuggle/xuggle2624685369771797713.tmp; error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/xuggle/xuggle2624685369771797713.tmp: /tmp/xuggle/xuggle2624685369771797713.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
08:43:05.565 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path
```

Same JAR works fine on Windows.

I tried to include xuggler-5.4.jar, 5.2.jar, I also tried to make maven project and to compile with maven, the problem persists.

Here is the CLASSPATH, so you can see I also included lately in the classpath the jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64//jre/lib/ext:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64//lib/tools.jar:/home/baidoc/libs/xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar

Comment: Same problem here after 10 years! Mac and Windows works, Raspbian not working. Project is compiled by maven